# Set default value in RequestBody if variable is empty or null

Tags: java, spring

I have example controller method

```
public void generateFile(@RequestBody final FileRequest request) {
...
}
```

Sometimes not all fields of this class *FileRequest* are filled, is there any way to set the default value when the value in the request is empty or null?

I mean something like @Default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In FileRequest class, setting field with a value. If field not filled, it will use default value in class. Use lombok, class is too simple. like as below:

```java
// class User
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String address="beijing";
    private int age=10;
}

// in Class restConctroller

   @RequestMapping(value = "/res1/data")
    public Object postData(@RequestBody User user){
        return user;
    }
```

after post http://localhost:8080/res1/data with name='aaa', you will get result as

```json
{
  "name": "aaa",
  "address": "beijing",
  "age": 10
}
```