# Is there a way to declare a default value in a @RequestBody field similar to defaultValues in @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

We have this request body which is supposed to map query params when an endpoint is accessed

```
// Uses Lombok @Data
public class RetrieveTxnRequest {

  private Short pageStart = 0;

  private Short pageSize = Short.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

But when we call the endpoint like this:

```
serverUrl/ourEndpoint?pageSize=
```

`pageSize` is set to `null`. If we supply a value it works. I noticed that if instead of using a class we use @RequestParams, the problem does not occur:

```
@GetMapping("/ourEndpoint")
public OurResponse getTransactions(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") Short pageStart,
                                   @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "50") Short pageSize)
```

because default values are set.

I tried the ff:

```
// Uses Lombok @Data
public class RetrieveTxnRequest {

  private Short pageStart = 0;

  @Value("50")
  private Short pageSize = Short.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work, pageSize is still null if we use the endpoint mentioned above

tldr: Is there a way to set default values in Spring @RequestBody classes?

Comment: It looks like you are reinventing `Pageable` btw.

Comment: Lombok `Data` will create a AllArgsConstructor for you so the values you set on your fields are ignored because they will be overriden anyway when spring calls this constructor.

Comment: @MichałKrzywański that seems to make sense. Is the best answer to use `@RequestParam`? What if there are many fields?

Answer (score 0):

use [nulls=Nulls.SKIP](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/Nulls.html#SKIP)

```
@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP)
private Short pageSize = 50;
```

Comment: Hello this doesn't seem to work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value in the class and it will be treated as a default value.

```
public class RetrieveTxnRequest {

  private Short pageStart = 0;

  private Short pageSize = "default_value";
}
```

Also refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64348731/set-default-value-in-requestbody-if-variable-is-empty-or-null) for this response

Comment: Assigning `String` to `Short`?

Comment: "default_value" means that the deafult value you want to assign to the pageSize, You can assign there.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried recreating your problem I think in this way you try putting your default values in request body classes.

I created a RequestBody class like this

```
public class RetrieveTxnRequest {

  private Short pageStart = 0;
  
  private Short pageSize = 1;

  public Short getPageStart() {
    return pageStart;
}

public void setPageStart(Short pageStart) {
    this.pageStart = pageStart;
}

public Short getPageSize() {
    return pageSize;
}

public void setPageSize(Short pageSize) {
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
}
```

}

And created a request handler method like this

```
@GetMapping("/ourEndpoint")
public RetrieveTxnRequest getTransactions(@RequestBody RetrieveTxnRequest rTxnRequest) {
    return rTxnRequest;
}
```

And I tried sending data through postman body every time if the data is there it is ignored otherwise default data is coming.
[image: postman]

Comment: I must add that adding a body to a get request that alters the response does not follow the the HTTP/1.1 spec, section 4.3 recommendation as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body#:~:text=Yes.,semantic%20meaning%20to%20the%20request.). So, your answer is advocating bad practices. Please change your answer accordingly.